# How do I lower OS /system resource usage /adjust for best performance?

Tags: performance, graphics, resolution, resources

Lets say I want to dedicate all resources in running some code so I would like to decrease operating system usage as much as possible  i.e. the mac equivalent of adjusting for best performance (e.g. in windows you can adjust for best performance make the whole thing look like windows 95 inorder to conserve resources I want to know how to do that for a mac.) totally get rid of extraneous/ overly fine graphics animations etc

Using a Mac OS catalina

Comment: Which hardware is in play? Does activity monitor show any graphic delay whatsoever?

Comment: @bmike   I just want to know what I can do in general to lower system resource use by graphics  i.e. the mac equivalaent of setting windows adjust for best performance which makes the thing look like Win 95  in order to lower resource usage.

Answer (score -2):

[App Tamer](https://www.stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/) may satisfy your requirements.